# Difference between Kubernetes ingress controller and CNI plugin?

Tags: kubernetes

As I understand it, [Calico](https://www.projectcalico.org/) is a [CNI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/) (Container Network Interface) plugin. [Traefik](https://traefik.io/) on the other hand, is an [ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/).

Is it correct to say that a CNI enables communication within a cluster, and an ingress controller enables communication from outside of the cluster to reach the inside of the cluster?

If that is the case, is it also correct that you can (must?) run both a CNI *and* an ingress controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it correct to say that a CNI enables communication within a
>   cluster, and an ingress controller enables communication from outside
>   of the cluster to reach the inside of the cluster?

More precisely, CNI is in charge of Pod to Pod communications and you are correct an ingress controller is a controller that uses *Ingress Rules* to handle the inbound traffic to access services within the cluster.

> If that is the case, is it also correct that you can (must?) run both a CNI and an ingress controller?

You must have a CNI plugin, you can choose different implementations (L2, L3 or overlay). Each k8s provider installs one by default. E.g minikube use the Docker Networking model by default. On the other hand, the ingress controller is highly recommended (but not must), you should use an ingress controller to route external requests to our services.